# If there exists a family of open sets covering this whole interval?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Problem:** Given is the interval $[-1, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. We then define a topology $\tau$ on this interval as follows. We call a subset $U \subset [-1, 1]$ open if $0 \notin U$ or if $(-1, 1) \subset U$.

Now suppose that $\mathcal{A} \subset \tau$ is a family of open sets such that $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A = [-1, 1]$. Does there then exist a finite subset of $\mathcal{A}$ which also covers this interval?

I don't think this is possible. But I'm not sure how to prove that there doesn't exist such a family. I was also trying to work with some examples, like $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-1 + \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) = (-1,1) $$ but this is no good since not every element of this collection contains $(-1,1)$ and so they are not open.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are the sets of your decomposition open? They contain $0$ and do not contain the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: That's why i'm saying it is a bad example. Read my last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A = [-1,1]$, in particular we have $0 \in \bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A$. Thus, there exists $A_0 \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $0 \in A_0$. Since $A_0$ is open, it must be $(-1,1) \subseteq A_0$.

Similarly, since $-1, 1 \in \bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A$ there exist $A_{-1}, A_1 \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $-1 \in A_{-1}$ and $1 \in A_1$.

Thus, $A_{-1} \cup A_0 \cup A_1 = [-1,1]$ so there exists a finite subcover of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: How do you know the union is not bigger than $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @Kamil Each $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is an open set in your topology $\tau$, so $A \subseteq [-1,1]$.